# JOOQ - convert result into Pojo

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have seen that JOOQ can automatically return a POJO when we use `.selectFrom(TABLE)` or  `.fetchInto(POJO.class);`

But is it possible to convert the result of a complex query into multiple POJO ?

Example :

This query will return an array of all columns into tables Support and Box. It is possible to convert them into a Support and Box Pojo ?

```
Result<Record> results = query.select()
                         .from(BOX)
                         .join(SUPPORT)
                         .on(SUPPORT.ID.equal(BOX.SUPPORT_ID))
                         .where(SUPPORT.ID.equal("XXXX"))
                         .orderBy(BOX.ID)
                         .fetch();
```

I have tested the method `.intoGroups(SUPPORT.ID, Box.class)` , it works fine. But I doesn't have the support object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Instantiate to [SelectSeekStep1](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectSeekStep1.html)

With [aliases](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/aliased-tables/) it's more convenient:

```
Box b = BOX.as("b");
Support s = SUPPORT.as("s");

SelectSeekStep1<Integer, Integer> sql = query.select(b.ID, s.ID /* other columns */)
     .from(b)
     .join(s)
        .on(s.ID.eq(b.SUPPORT_ID))
     .where(s.ID.eq("XXXX"))
     .orderBy(b.ID)
;
```

#### Then just fetch what/as you need:

```
List<BoxRecord> boxes = sql.fetchInto(BOX); 
SupportRecord support = sql.limit(1).fetchOneInto(SUPPORT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have test it, but it don't have the expected result. For the box, it is Ok, but when I do SupportRecord support = sql.limit(1).fetchOneInto(SUPPORT); it is the Box id which come into the SupportRecord.ID (because they have the same field name ?)

Comment: @ascott: [That's a known issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3634). For the time being, you'll have to remove the alias, i.e. the call to `as("b")` and `as("s")`.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, if you want to achieve the same behaviour with insert methods you should use:

```
insertInto(BOX)
    .set(BOX.COLUMN1, UInteger.valueOf(1))
    .set(BOX.COLUMN2, "test")
    .returning()
    .fetchOne()
    .into(<POJO_class>.class);
```